# Is artifice admissible into cosmological models of mainstream physics?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology

This question depends on my reading of Nikodem J. Poplawski's "Cosmology with torsion" (visible at https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.0587), an alternative version of cosmic inflation that's dependent on effects of torsion, in the interaction between fermions newly-materialized within the volume previously occupied by the mass of any large rotating star and the vastly-larger fermions of the star itself (after initiation of a gravitational collapse of that star by the complete expenditure of its nuclear fuel):  Because all fermions spin, that interaction would realign the trajectories of many of the newly-materialized  fermions, and greatly accelerate their passage over those trajectories, with their rate of passage eventually slowing, quasi-inertially, in their formation of a new "local universe" on smaller spatial and temporal scales, analogous in shape to the skin of a basketball.

As discussed in the article "Mystery Object Blurs Line Between Neutron Stars and Black Holes" in "The Scientific American" of June 30, 2020, the addition of mass to any rotating star otherwise apt to collapse into a neutron star  would result in its collapse into a black hole instead.  (The article hypothesizes that the added mass might be as small as "an apple", whereas, until the observation which it discusses, it would've been assumed to comprise a number of solar masses.) If any advanced civilization (either our own in its future, or others), convinced of the validity of Poplawski's past- and future-eternal cosmological model, would want to increase the frequency and density of whatever reiterations of the beings comprising its dominant species might occur by increasing the frequency and density of whatever recurrences of any such species' spatio-temporal environment might itself occur, then the proportion of black holes to neutron stars in its observable region would tend to increase.

In inflationary models based on 1915's General Relativity, fermions are idealized as "point-like", whereas in Poplawski's model (which is based on the Einstein-Cartan-Sciama-Kibble theory, developed by Einstein and Cartan in 1929 and modified, a few decades later, by Sciama and Kibble), they have a tiny spatial extent, which is, nevertheless, not as small as the Planck length.  (In this connection, I'd like to mention the fact that the "strings" of string theory also have spatial extent:  When equated to particles, they are idealized as tubes.)

The sequentially-smaller local universes of Poplawski's model (which, in his terminology, include our own, whose name is capitalized as "the" Universe) each inherit their direction of passage through time from their "parenting" LU, and the model itself requires no "singularity" of infinite density.  It is falsifiable if there is no prevalent direction of rotation in the local universe, but, even in our observable part of it, so many factors are involved in the motion of astronomical objects that no such conclusion has yet been reached definitively.

I'm hoping, in this question, to verify whether physics might generally permit the incorporation of artifice (those additions of mass that I mentioned in my 2nd paragraph) into comparisons of the validity of cosmological models.  (It appears to me that it would, as the 2nd law of thermodynamics, for example, was developed substantially through successful attempts to improve the efficiency of locomotives, but, as a child of wildly adversarial times, I'm not certain of that. )

I've been encouraged to post this question partly by Guth's hypothetical discussion of limitations and possibilities of artifical creation of local universes in the 1997 edition of his book "The Inflationary Universe", and partly by the 100 references (whose authors were much larger in number) itemized in Mandal's paper "Effects of torsion on the radiation fields in curved spacetime", in Physics Letters B of Sept. 2020 (currently available free online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physletb.2020.135778), which challenges a torsion-free connection as one remaining unproven assumption of General Relativity.

Comment: Is the question whether alien technology is allowed as an explanation in cosmology?

Comment: Not necessarily, as (for instance) the addition of an apple to a star that had been about to collapse into a neutron star could be accomplished with a drone of our existing technology (cf. Voyager).

Comment: But you said it was for "comparisons of the validity of cosmological models". As far as I know, human beings aren't already engaged in astronomical engineering, so if you want to explain observed features of the universe as artificial in origin, it will have to be the work of aliens...

Comment: Inasmuch as the effects of engineering might be fully intentional, that'd be true, but, as it's now well-established enough that engineering will have side effects that are both unintentional and unavoidable (-for instance, the pollution created by locomotives, electric railway powerhouses, autos, and planes are all effects of the engineering of transportation systems), it's not an absolute truth. The quantities of mass humans have deposited on Luna & Mars will have tiny effects on the future trajectories of those huge bodies, and discernment of their desirability is impractical. – Edouard

Comment: The same is true of whatever intermittent prolongations of life may result from reiterations in inflationary models (which are generally hypothesized as being at least eternal to the future), as their desirability will vary between the lives of different individuals:  However, what I'm mainly wanting to point out, in these postings, is the fact that torsion-based models appear to have an observational proof available that other models may inherently lack.

Comment: Can you say again what this observational proof is, and how it is related to artifice?

Comment: The observational proof would be an increase in the ratio of BH's to neutron stars:  In other words, either an INCREASE in the no. of observable BH's that would represent a LARGER proportion of their current no. than a commensurate increase in the no. of observable neutron stars would represent in THEIR no., or (much less probably) a DECREASE in the no. of observable black holes that would represent a SMALLER proportion of their no. than whatever decrease in the no. of neutron stars would represent in THEIR no., with either such change occurring over an identical period of our time.

Comment: The reason for the increase in the proportion of BH's would perhaps be due to those artificial additions of mass to stars about to collapse, that I'd mentioned earlier and that may have conceivably been the reason for the size of the "mystery object" discussed in the Sci.Am. article.  (I'd actually hypothesized the possibility in my May postings on PSE's question "Is time emergent from quantum entanglement?", and I believe the actual astronomical event was discussed on the BBC as early as June.  As periodicals are hard to get from libraries now, I'm unsure of its current status.)

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the idea is: If there are more stellar-mass black holes than expected, it could be because aliens are deliberately adding mass to neutron stars to turn them into black holes, in order to create more child universes... Please see https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9402104 , where other reasons for creating black holes are mentioned, but which also considers child universes, albeit in a different context (a hypothetical scrambling of natural constants from one universe generation to the next, leading to cosmological natural selection for black hole fecundity).

Comment: @MitchellPorter --I read the preprint you'd recommended, and, seriously, it was quite interesting, as well as surprisingly free of formalism, considering that its author seems to be a math professor.  Although their simple resolution of Olbers' Paradox is what 1st drew me to them, the resemblance between cosmological models centered in BH's & biological reproduction has always been intriguing, &, as you'd said it reached conclusions opposite those suggested in the preprint you've cited, I'd guess I'm pleased to see that Smolin does not seem to have proceeded with his own paper.

Comment: The resemblance between the holographic principle (of projection from some origin to the inboard surface of a sphere an infinite distance away) seemed to be another point of resemblance between the Arxiv piece you'd recommended & Poplawski's relativistic cosmological model, although I'm a bit weak on quantum physics to be making comparisons involving it.

Comment: By the way, I guess you're right in characterizing our species as "alien" in relation to a more evolved future version of itself:  If there is one, it'd probably be cybernetic, or at least dependent on drones for its spatial explorations, given our apparent inability to react promptly, collectively, and appropriately to slight variations in microbiology even on earth....

Comment: At arxiv.org/pdf/2101.04068.pdf , there's a preprint of a 2021 paper which uses an unusually large sample of galaxies (77,840 of them) to show that preferred direction of rotation which was mentioned in the 4th paragraph of my question as a characteristic validating Poplawski's model.

Comment: It's interesting but no one is showing a mathematical derivation of the predicted effect from the underlying equations of motion. Poplawski's 2010 talks about "small corrections to the FLRW metric" but doesn't tell us what form they take. Poplawski 2013 https://doi.org/10.1080/21672857.2013.11519725 ends with several cosmological dipoles but again doesn't explain how his model would produce them. Shamir 2021 cites a different big-bang-from-black-hole theory ("holographic big bang model") but the papers cited don't talk about the child universe inheriting the rotation of the black hole...

Comment: ... it's Shamir who introduces this idea. I hope what I'm saying is clear: you can't just say, the primordial black hole is spinning, therefore the child universe is rotating too, therefore the observations are explained. It needs to be shown that this is what the underlying theory actually predicts. Maybe it makes sense as a kind of turbulent fragmentation, a single big vortex fragmenting into billions of smaller vortices which become the galaxies, but there needs to be a calculation... btw https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.05208 is a survey of current cosmological anomalies.

Comment: The inheritance of rotation from parent to child universes is actually a notion I'd picked up from Rutgers' Lindford in the Arxiv preprint of "Big Bounce or Double Bang?", although Poplawski's mentioned it in a couple of his many preprints on that site.  His verbal ambiguities had completely escaped me, but seem minor compared to those of Penrose, his main competitor in cosmologies verbally plausible to me.

Comment: I'd imagine (maybe incorrectly) that, given the swarms of ECT notation in Poplawski's paper, some of which Mitchell Porter was helpful enough to interpret for me (as lacking a clear connection to Einsteinian laws of motion), it might be a sort of feeler for actual responses before his investment of months or years of work integrating those responses into his views, although it does seem that Lior Shamir himself might favor a model other than Poplawski's.  Special Relativity was formulated 10 years before GR, whose 1st presentation took 370 pages.

Comment: @MitchellPorter --Mitchell, I remember that you had been interested in my remark that Lee Smolin had been attempting to construct a multiverse model that would provide for "infinite variety":  I don't know whether he has done so, but Laura Mersini-Houghton has, as described in a lecture of hers that's freely visible at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYVg50_w1UA   .

Comment: There are quite a few people working on quantum cosmology of inflationary multiverses and so on, is there a particular idea of hers that's significant?

Comment: Re Mitchell Porter's good point that the model in Poplawski's preprint left out any detail of the "corrections" that Poplawski had felt the FLRW metric to need for validation of his model, either the published article at https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269310011561 ,or its own "Erratum", linked to the subsequently published article, may have included them, as that erratum does include a change in the Friedmann equation.

Comment: The significance of Laura Mersini-Houghton's speech in defense of the multiverse concept lay (to me) in the fact that its description of an infinity of universes having infinite variety appeared consistent with her earlier rejection of "Poincare recurrence" (described in Wikipedia):  However, I believe her model includes a special central section of spacetime that other multiverses (including Poplawski's, which seems compatible with such recurrences) seem to lack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is artifice admissible into cosmological models of mainstream physics?

**Sure.**

If we consider that peer review process of [Classical and Quantum Gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_and_Quantum_Gravity) is a sufficient criteria for mainstream cosmological theory then the following paper would be a sufficient evidence for this:

- Olson, S. J. (2015). *Homogeneous cosmology with aggressively expanding civilizations*. Classical and Quantum Gravity, 32(21), 215025. [arXiv:1411.4359](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4359), [doi:10.1088/0264-9381/32/21/215025](https://doi.org/10.1088/0264-9381/32/21/215025).

As we can see there are words “cosmology” and “civilizations” right in the title.

Though this particular paper seems more concerned about the future than the present (quote from the abstract):

> We conclude that the existence of life, if certain advanced technologies are practical, could have a significant influence on the future large-scale evolution of the universe.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone reading this Q&A, I'd like to point out that the assessment of both my question & A.V.S.' answer was reduced to zero by someone not caring to leave any commentary, which, to me, implies that that reduction may well have been made by someone motivated by considerations (perhaps philosophical or religious) not bearing on physics or mathematics.  Although that reduction, nevertheless, apparently had some value to them under PSE's rating system, I'd consequently recommend that participants interested in physics disregard it.

Comment: For readers unfamiliar with details of the rating ("reputation") system, the "value" to which I'd referred was the 10-point reduction in reputation that's charged for downvotes.

Comment: Pas idee de comment mes commentaires ont ete traduit en francais, mais, pourvu que l'ordinateur ajoute tout marque diacritique, ca va pour moi! (Mes jours durent seulement 24 heures chacun!) – 
Edouard
 6 mins ago    Edit